# Module csv-writer , how to use import?

Tags: javascript, express, csv, es6-modules, import-csv

*Const createCSvwriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;*

How can we do it with import

Answer (score 2):

Looking at https://github.com/ryu1kn/csv-writer/blob/master/src/index.ts you should be able to do

```js
import { createObjectCsvWriter } from 'csv-writer'
```

Comment: This should be `createObjectCsvWriter` instead of `createCsvWriter`.